# Find clicked element when binding to a form submission event?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events

I think this should be simple. Say I've got the following jQuery:

```
$someForm.live('submit', function(event) {
// do something
});
```

If there is more than one submit button (`<button type="submit">`) in that form, and I want to refer to the `name` attribute of the button that was clicked, how would I do that within the callback function?

### Update - Clarification

In the callback context, both `this` and `event.target` refer to the form itself, and `event` is a deeply nested object. It may contain what I'm looking for, but I haven't found it  yet.

Another way to phrase this question would be, "if I'm watching for a submit event on a form (not its child elements), is there any way, when I handle that event, to determine the child element from which the event bubbled up to the form?" **Is the clicked element even available at that point, or does the browser just consider it an event on the form itself that had no deeper origin?**

### Update 2 - Answer

It appears that the answer is what Nick Craver said - that **the submit event originates at the form itself, so it can't be traced back to the button, which had a click event, not a submit event.** In order to get any further information from the click, it's necessary to have a click listener for the button.

In some cases (like mine), you may need both 1) to capture which submit button is clicked and 2) to bind to the submit event on the form. For example, if you're using jQuery Validate, it prevents the form from submitting until it's valid. If you make the form submit via ajax by binding to the button click, you'll bypass that validation.

As Nick showed, you can solve this by capturing the button info using a click listener for the buttons, and then use this information in the form's submission callback.

A clean way to pass the button's info from the click callback to the form's submission callback is to use `jQuery.data()` to store the it on the form.  For example:

```
// In the button's click event callback...
jQuery.data($someForm, 'lastSubmitButton', event.target.name);

// In the form's submit event callback...
var whichButton = jQuery.data($someForm, 'lastSubmitButton');
```

This prevents the need for a global variable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Normally* you can use [`event.target`](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) for the element itself...and in this case, since it's a native DOM property, just use `.name` as well:

```
$someForm.live('submit', function(event) {
  var name = event.target.name;
});
```

However, since `submit` doesn't originate from the button, only a click does, you want [something more like this](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JQTA6/1/):

```
$("form :submit").live('click', function(event) {
  var name = this.name;
});
```

Use `this` here, because as @[patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) points out, a `<button>` can have children as well, and the target may be a child in those cases.

Comment: I just tried logging `event.target`, and that gives me the form - same as `this`. I think it's because I'm binding to the submit event on the form itself.

Comment: @Nathan - is an additional handler on the element itself an option, like this? http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JQTA6/

Comment: @Nick: I'd note that a `<button>` can have content, so `event.target` (in a `click` handler) may not necessarily reference the `<button>` itself. Though `.closest()` would take care of it. :o)

Comment: @patrick - true, so this would probly be the best solution: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JQTA6/1/

Comment: @Nick - I can do that if necessary, but I was trying to see if I could avoid binding something else on the submit buttons themselves.

Comment: Using `this` would certainly be better than `.closest()`. My mind was still on the handler being on the `<form>`.

Comment: @Nathan - unfortunately it's just not available there because a `submit` event *originates* on the `<form>` *from* the `click` (or other means), but in either case it doesn't bubble to the `<form>`.

Comment: You could reduce it to one additional handler by placing a `click` on the `form` and testing the `event.target`, or just use `.delegate()`. EDIT: Would only register clicks, though.

Comment: @Nick - hmmm. This is tricky. I want to bind to the form's submit function because the callback does an ajax submission instead. I want that ajax submission to send a different parameter based on which button was clicked. But I'm also using jQuery Validate to prevent the form from submitting unless it's valid. So if I do my ajax stuff when a button is clicked, I think I'll bypass the form validation.

Comment: @Nathan - you can do a combination, for example just have the `click` handler set a variable, `submitButton = this;`, then use that in your `submit` handler...so the click just updates the last clicked submit button, the `<form>` submit event uses it, like this: http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/JQTA6/2/

Comment: @Nick - had one more thought and updated the question accordingly. I think it's cleaner to use the `.data()` method than to use a global variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [target](http://api.jquery.com/event.target/) property of the `event` object to get the element that initiated the event:

```
$(":submit").click(function(event) {
    var initiatingElement = event.target;
    // Do something with `initiatingElement`...
});
```

**EDIT:** Note that, for that to work, you will have to handle the `click` events of your submit buttons instead of the `submit` event of your form.

Comment: This isn't working for me - please see comment on Nick's answer above.

Comment: That's correct. Thanks for your help! I accepted Nick's answer because he gave a bit more explanation and followup help. See my updated answer for some thoughts on implementation.