# Determine active input when form is submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

Is there a generic solution to determining which input (e.g., text, submit button, etc.) was used to submit a form using jQuery or plain Javascript?

I'm well aware that you can bind to click events on submit buttons:

```
$('[type=submit]').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var $submit = $(this);
    $submit.closest('form').trigger('submit', [$submit]);
});
```

I'm also aware that you can listen for the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key on text inputs:

```
$('input').on('keypress', function(event) {
    if (event.which == 13) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $input = $(this);
        $input.closest('form').trigger('submit', [$input]);
    }
});
```

Where the form listens for the submit event:

```
$('#the_form').on('submit', function(event, $submit) {
    // ...
});
```

But is there a more generic solution without the need for special logic for submit buttons and text inputs (and any future type of input)?

Comment: Did you see [jQuery: Find clicked element when binding to a form submission event](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429823/jquery-find-clicked-element-when-binding-to-a-form-submission-event)?

Comment: @Stan That basically describes what I mentioned with binding on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered seeing what element has the focus on submit?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var target = null;
    $('#the_form :input').focus(function() {
        target = this;
        alert(target);
    });
    $('#the_form').submit(function() {
        alert(target);
    });
});
```