# AngularJS: How to determine which text input field fired submit?

Tags: angularjs, ng-submit

I would like to process the inputs of a form individually. If I press enter after typing, and the `ng-submit` expression is executed, how can I get passed the responsible input field to the submit callback to determine which input to process?

Is it possible without a hack and without splitting the form in several mini forms?

Comment: May be this http://stackoverflow.com/a/4429834/2435473 could help you..

Comment: Well, this is jQuery not Angular...

Comment: you could convert it easily by wraping it in directive..

Comment: I do not know what you mean by "convert". Can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1):

I would not use ng-submit for this (submit is for a form rather than the single text inputs if i am not mistaken). Just use ng-keydown to get the enter key event and pass an identifier for the text field.

```
<input type="text" ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event, 'input1')" >
<input type="text" ng-keydown="onKeyDown($event, 'input2')" >
```

and in the Controller:

```
$scope.onKeyDown = function(event, id) {

    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        // enter was pressed for the input id
    }
};
```

Comment: What if submit is triggered by an imaginable different source, for instance numpad enter? How can I make sure `keyCode` will always equal 13 on submit? Isn't this browser-dependent?

Comment: Enter should be fine. I don't know which other keys will trigger a submit. But if you still want to use ng-submit, you can pass the $event variable in the same way. If the input field has an id or something it should be identifiable from the values within these args.